# Custom router in Magento-2(SCO Friendly URL)

Tags: magento2

Anyone knows an alternative way to implement Fancy URL(This won't affect url_rewrite table entries) for Magento 2, as we had for Magento 1 as mentioned here:  http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/29/simple-url-rewrite-using-magento-xml/

> I need to inject product SKU this way: http://example.com/book/sku/xyz
>   I've implemented it in one of my Magento 1 project using Fancy URL concept, but couldn't find an alternative for Magento 2. Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve using **custom router** in Magento 2. Here is well-explained documentation regarding your requirement: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/routing.html

---

If you wany fancy URL for catalog pages, you can also achieve uit using plugin.

In your custom module, Create `di.xml` file under `etc/frontend` folder and write below plugin declaration there:

```
<type name="\Magento\UrlRewrite\Controller\Router">
    <plugin name="mycompany_seo_friendly_url" type="Mycompany\Seo\Plugin\Controller\Router"/>
</type>
```

Now, create a plugin class named `Router.php` at `Mycompany\Seo\Plugin\Controller\Router` location with below content:

```
namespace Mycompany\Seo\Plugin\Controller;

class Router
{

    /**
     * @param \Magento\UrlRewrite\Controller\Router $subject
     * @param $request
     * @return null
     */
    public function beforeMatch(
        \Magento\UrlRewrite\Controller\Router $subject,
        $request
    ) {
        $identifier = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');
        if (strpos($identifier, 'sku') !== false) {
            $urlRequest = $this->getKeyByString($identifier, "sku");
            $productSku = $this->getValueByKey($identifier, "sku");
            $request->setPathInfo($urlRequest);
            if($productSku != null) {$request->setParam('sku', $productSku);}
        }
        return null;
    }

    public function getValueByKey($string, $key)
    {
        if (strpos($string, "/" . $key . "/") !== false){
            $urlArray = explode("/" . $key . "/", $string);
            if (count($urlArray) > 0) {
                $value = $urlArray[1];
                if (strpos($urlArray[1], '/') !== false) {
                    $value = substr($urlArray[1], 0, strpos($urlArray[1], '/'));
                }
                return $value;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public function getKeyByString($string, $key)
    {
        if (strpos($string, "/" . $key . "/") !== false) {
            $urlArray = explode("/" . $key . "/", $string);
            if (isset($urlArray[0]) && $urlArray[0] != "") {
                return $urlArray[0];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Let me check.

Comment: It's work for me. Thank you so much. :-)

Comment: Happy to help @PratikMehta :)